# How to generate a survey curve with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns WorkItem and LiveDays. For example

```
| WorkItem | LiveDays | 
| A        | 8        | 
| B        | 2        | 
| C        | 5        | 
....
```

I would like to generate a survey data of the work item. Each item is normalized as starting from day 1 and ending to LiveDays, and value of nth day is how many workitems is still live (in process). For example

```
| Days | Counter | Comments | 
| 1    | 3       | (A, B, C)| 
| 2    | 3       | (A, B, C)|
| 3    | 2       | (A, C)   |
| 4    | 2       | (A, C)   |
| 5    | 2       | (A, C)   |
| 6    | 1       | (A)      |
| 7    | 1       | (A)      |
| 8    | 1       | (A)      |
```

Is it possible to use SQL query instead of inserting data into a new table with transaction?

Thanks

Comment: What is a survey curve?

Comment: It is just how many work items are still alive on a specific day. After normalize the workitems, we could assume that all of them starting from day 1 and end at LiveDays as the example.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added several databases I could use

Comment: Every database is slightly different, choose one unless you need cross database compatability.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. *Is it possible to use SQL query instead of inserting data into a new table with transaction?* Of course.

Answer (score 0):

To show it can be done (it does after all answer your original question) here's your example reproduced using Db2 Developer-C 11.1 on dbfiddle.uk: (You **did** say there were several databases you could use, and this will no doubt serve to illustrate that different databases do things in different ways!). **Note:** additional MySQL solution further down.

```
CREATE TABLE surveydata AS (
WITH t1(workitem, livedays)
     AS (VALUES ('A', 8), ('B', 2), ('C', 5)),
     numbers(seq)
     AS (VALUES (1)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT seq + 1
         FROM   numbers
         WHERE  seq < (SELECT MAX(livedays)
                       FROM   t1)),
     xdata(workitem, ndays)
     AS (SELECT workitem,
                seq
         FROM   t1,
                numbers
         WHERE  seq <= livedays)
SELECT ndays AS "Days",
       COUNT(*) AS "Counter",
       '(' || LISTAGG(workitem, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY workitem) || ')' AS "Comments"
FROM   xdata
GROUP  BY ndays
) WITH DATA;
```

with the result of `SELECT * FROM surveydata` as below ==>

[image]

UPDATE: With a bit more fiddling, I've managed to get a solution using MySQL 8.0 as well:

```
WITH recursive t1(workitem, livedays)
    AS (SELECT 'A', 8 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 5 ),
numbers(seq)
AS (SELECT 1 AS seq
    UNION ALL
    SELECT seq + 1
    FROM   numbers
    WHERE  seq < (SELECT MAX(livedays)
                    FROM t1)),
xdata(workitem, ndays)
AS (SELECT workitem,
           seq
      FROM t1,
           numbers
     WHERE seq <= livedays)
  SELECT   ndays                                                                     AS "Days",
           COUNT(*)                                                                  AS "Counter" ,
           CONCAT('(', GROUP_CONCAT(workitem ORDER BY workitem SEPARATOR ', '), ')') AS "Comments"
  FROM     xdata
  GROUP BY ndays;
```